# JAX-WS XML file attachment

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws, mtom

I am currently working on an web app which has web services allowing user to upload xml files to server. I am using JAX-WS to create web services. All examples I've seen describe uploading image files. Hence web service would contain a method like:

```
@WebMethod String uploadImage(Image data);
```

However, in case if I am uploading  XML file what would be the type of arguments for that method?

```
@WebMethod String uploadXML(????? data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question!

```
@WebMethod
public int uploadXML(DataHandler xmlData)
```

javax.activation.DataHandler has method getInputStream which contains the XML file sent as attachment